# Где можно почитать про тесты?что это такое и как их делать?

Tags: тестирование

Везде все пишут про тесты,Unit тесты,но нигде не могу найти информации про них,где и как  и что это.Буду благодарен если поможете найти обучающую информацию!

А для каждого языка своё собственное тестирование?для php допустим
я просто хотел почитать про основы,сомневаюсь что тестирование для c++ сильно отличается от тестирования для java или php того же.Ну синтаксически то естественно,но основная идея же должна быть одинакова.Или я вообще не прав?Объясните пожалуйста если можете

Спасибо,пойду штрудить мануал для phpunit)))

Comment: slideshare.net/amritayan/test-driven-development-in-c

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие учебные материалы по тестированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451404/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Модульное тестирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

В статье есть раздел "Инструментарий", где есть ссылки на соответствующие инструменты в помощь юнит-тестеру на том или ином языке (технологии)

Что-нибудь более конкретное интересует?

Answer (score 0):

Я изучал основы NUnit тут
http://www.vr-online.ru/content/nunit-delaem-testy-pravilno-3054
http://www.vr-online.ru/content/c-nunit-delaem-testy-pravilno-chast-2-3343

Comment: Интересно стало. Прочитал первую ссылку. Тестируют сумму 2-х 32-bit целых без знака. Причем на примере 2 + 3.

Несколько очевидных assert-ов, но на переполнение проверить автор не догадывается.

В конце - резюме

     При том, если ты хочешь устроиться на работу в серьезную софтверную компанию, то там точно без NUnit (или подобного ПО ) никуда.

Лично мне по подобному поводу хочется сказать:

     Можешь использовать ПО для тестирования, а можешь не использовать - без головы толку все равно не будет.

**Проблема же в этих штуках это то, что правильные тесты они составлять никак не помогают**.

Comment: (продолжение)

Я помню мне очень понравилась (прямо глаза на тестирование открыла) одна небольшая книжка

[Искусство тестирования программ](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/18319458/) (наверняка можно где-нибудь ее и задаром качнуть).

Набор тестов для программы, определяющей (насколько помню) по координатам 3-х точек является ли треугольник равнобедренным меня просто потряс (в хорошем смысле).

Answer (score 0):

Есть хорошая книга по тест-дизайну и не только. Она правда на английском, но вроде всё вполне понятно)

A Practitioner's Guide to Software Test Design by Lee Copeland